# Memory-friendly way to save Bitmap raw bytes

Tags: android, bitmap

I would look for a more memory-friendly way to get the raw pixel data from a `Bitmap` to a stream.

```
fun Bitmap.toStreamRaw(stream: OutputStream) {
  ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4).also {
    copyPixelsToBuffer(it)
    stream.write(it.array())
  }
}
```

This standard solution needs to allocate a buffer, a second copy of the bitmap just for the purpose of storing it into the stream. For larger bitmaps and smaller devices, this just plain doesn't work. My current workaround is to catch `OutOfMemoryError` and call another function that renders the bitmap in bands and while that has a lower memory footprint, it's understandably much slower.

Comment: Rewrite copyPixelsToBuffer(it) to writePixelsToStream()..

Comment: I'd be glad to do so. The only problem is that I can't find anything like that in https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap :-)) Am I missing something?

Comment: There is bitmap.getPixel(x, y) which gives you an int. Write all the int's to stream looping over all x and y. Compare with what copyPixelsToBuffer() writes.

Comment: All that's `GetPixel()` is good for is having a laugh. For a specific image, straight copy takes 44-50 ms, banded (but still `copyPixelToBuffer()`, only operating on 256-pixel-high bands created) 350-400, about ten times slower. `GetPixel()` takes 2.4 seconds (!). I could also call `GetPixels()` for somewhat larger chunks but that wouldn't be the solution, either.

Comment: Actually, now I remember, `GetPixels()` returns the whole bitmap, so no use in this case (yes, you can specify which part, it will only fill that part but will still return the whole width and height; quite stupid if you ask me).